# beamer actionenv and modes

Tags: beamer, overlays

Is it possible to have a beamer environment completely discarded in a given mode?

In the following MWE, I'd like the 2nd `actionenv` `tikzpicture` environment to be centered with the items of the other column but there is some vertical space added from the first `actionenv` even though it's not displayed in beamer mode. I work around this problem by using wrapping the `trikzpicture` in a `\only<article>` (see the 2nd frame) but I don't see why it's needed.

Of course I could remove all the `actionenv` environments and just use the `\only<article>` macros but for some reasons (the file is created by `org-mode` export), I can't.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{standalone,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.45\columnwidth}
      \begin{actionenv}<article>
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw [very thick, red, ->] (0,0) -- (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{actionenv}
      \begin{actionenv}<presentation>
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw [very thick, red, ->] (0,0) -- (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{actionenv}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\columnwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item 1st item
      \item 2nd item
      \item 3rd item
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.45\columnwidth}
      \begin{actionenv}<article>
        \only<article>{
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [very thick, red, ->] (0,0) -- (4,4);
          \end{tikzpicture}
        }
      \end{actionenv}
      \begin{actionenv}<presentation>
        \only<presentation>{
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [very thick, red, ->] (0,0) -- (4,4);
          \end{tikzpicture}
      }
      \end{actionenv}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\columnwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item 1st item
      \item 2nd item
      \item 3rd item
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

That seems to be a good case for the `onlyenv` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{standalone,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.45\columnwidth}
      \begin{onlyenv}<article>
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw [very thick, red, ->] (0,0) -- (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{onlyenv}
      \begin{onlyenv}<presentation>
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw [very thick, red, ->] (0,0) -- (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{onlyenv}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\columnwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item 1st item
      \item 2nd item
      \item 3rd item
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]